# I get this error The getter 'length' was called on null Receiver: null : Tried calling: length I/flutter

Tags: flutter, getter

```
import '../models/activity_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

   class Trip {
   String id;
   String city;
  String name;
  List<Activity> ;
  DateTime date;
  Trip({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.city,
    @required this.activities,
    @required this.date,
  }) : id = UniqueKey().toString();
}

trip_activityList.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../models/activity_model.dart';

class TripActivityList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Activity> activities;
  TripActivityList({this.activities});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: activities.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(activities[index].name);
        });
  }
}

trip_activities.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uvs_voyage/views/trip/widgets/trip_activity_list.dart';

import '../../../models/activity_model.dart';

class TripActivities extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Activity> activities;
  TripActivities({this.activities});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.blue[100],
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: 'En cours',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Terminé',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 600,
              child: TabBarView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  TripActivityList(
                    activities: activities,
                  ),
                  TripActivityList(
                    activities: activities,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)       /I/flutter (15602): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15602): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building TripActivityList(dirty):
I/flutter (15602): The setter 'length=' was called on null.
I/flutter (15602): Receiver: null
I/flutter (15602): Tried calling: length=0
I/flutter (15602):
I/flutter (15602): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (15602):   TripActivityList
I/flutter (15602):   file:///C:/Users/Mamadou%20Lamine%20Bouss/uvs_voyage/lib/views/trip/widgets/trip_activities.dart:35:19
I/flutter (15602):
I/flutter (15602): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (15602): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter (15602): #1      TripActivityList.build (package:uvs_voyage/views/trip/widgets/trip_activity_list.dart:11:31)
I/flutter (15602): #2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4620:28)
I/flutter (15602): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
I/flutter (15602): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter (15602): #5      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:5)
I/flutter (15602): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
I/flutter (15602): #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter (15602): #9      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:5)
I/flutter (15602): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
I/flutter (15602): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
I/flutter (15602): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
I/flutter (15602): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter (15602): #17     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:5)
I/flutter (15602): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
I/flutter (15602): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter (15602): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
I/flutter (15602): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
I/flutter (15602): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `activities` is possibly null when the Widget is instantiated.
You need to guard against the case when data == null

```
 itemCount: activities!= null ? activities.length : 0,
```

Comment: but I don't receive any data

Comment: You might have to convert it to a stateful widget that can refresh on data and in initState, set a parameter to widget.activites